# Linux command to fetch substring in file to be used for replacement further down in file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

a) Want to insert the line "// VERSION 221204  NEW LINE" before first "Kalle" line that comes after a line that starts with "Sune".

b) Also need to grab "any substring"(word) and use that to replace VERSION in the line that is described in a) above. So, the line added above should be "//  221204  NEW LINE"

This is an example of a file to edit:

> Arne
>
> Kalle
>
> Annika "any substring" Anna    (Comment: Annika is unique in the file)
>
> Sigge
>
> Sune Berra
>
> Kalle

Command:
`sed '/Sune.*/,/Kalle/!b;/Kalle/i // VERSION 221204  NEW LINE' <file>`

This is the line I get, okay so far.

> Arne
>
> Kalle
>
> Annika Lisa Anna
>
> Sigge
>
> Sune Berra
>
> // VERSION 221204  NEW LINE
>
> Kalle

But what I also want is to fetch Lisa () and use that to replace VERSION. So the new line should then be:
// Lisa 221204  NEW LINE

This can be used to fetch Lisa `(<any substring>). | awk '/Annika /{print $(NF-1)}'`

But how can this be put together?
Can "Lisa" be fetched first and saved somehow, for use in later replace?

One liner would be good. And I want bash, linux commands like sed, awk...

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```bash
sed -E '{

/Kalle/!{n;b}
:A /Annika/!{n;bA}
:B /Sune/!{N;bB}
/Annika[[:space:]]+([[:alpha:]]+).*/{
  s//&\n\n\/\/ \1 221204 NEW LINE/
 }

}' file
```

One-liner:

```bash
sed -E '/Kalle/!{n;b}; :A /Annika/!{n;bA}; :B /Sune/!{N;bB}; /Annika[[:space:]]+([[:alpha:]]+).*/{s//&\n\n\/\/ \1 221204 NEW LINE/}' file
```

Comment: Thanks,


It works.


sed -E '/Kalle/!{n;b}; :A /Annika/!{n;bA}; :B /Sune/!{N;bB}; /Annika[[:space:]]+([[:alpha:]]+).*/{s//&\n\n\/\/ \1 221204 NEW LINE/}' <file>d
Arne

Kalle

Annika Lisa Anna

Sigge

Sune Berra

// Lisa 221204 NEW LINE

Kalle

===================================
BTW.

How would the command look like if I want to do an inline update of the file?

This doesn't work:

sed -i '/Kalle/!{n;b}; :A /Annika/!{n;bA}; :B /Sune/!{N;bB}; /Annika[[:space:]]+([[:alpha:]]+).*/{s//&\n\n\/\/ \1 221204 NEW LINE/}' test_nu

Comment: @RichardOlsson To edit the file in place. ``sed -i.bak -E <expressions>`` this will also create a backup copy of the original file.